# Does this integral have a closed-form answer?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Does this integral have a closed-form solution?

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^4\left(2x^{22}+\left(11\sqrt{5}+11\right)x^{17}-20\right)}{2\left(x^{22}+1\right)\sqrt{4\left(\sqrt{x^{22}+1}+x^{10}+(\sqrt{5}+1)x^{5}\right )+6+2\sqrt{5}}}dx$$

**EDIT**

Sorry for the lack of context, I was late for a compromise. I saw this integral in my university, in the notes of a professor. I asked him what it was, and as response I got "integrals that computers do not solve."

I plotted the integrand chart on the desmos site. The result was this:

### [image]

Clearly, the integral is convergent and probably has a value assigned to it.

Comment: Sorry for this. I already edited my first post.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt, I'm not sure how you got $x^{88}/x^{121}$ for the comparison.  I get $x^{26}/x^{27.5}=x^{-3/2}$. The integral still converges, but not super fast.

Comment: sry, that was a stupid miscalculation

Comment: Today my teacher showed me the development of this integral. When I have time, I'll post it here. I found it very curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much effort, I asked my teacher to solve this. Here's his solution:

You need to notice that $$4(\sqrt{x^{22}+1}+x^{10}+(\sqrt{5}+1)x^{5})+6+2\sqrt{5}=4\left (\sqrt{x^{22}+1}+x^{10}+(\sqrt{5}+1)x^{5}+\frac{6+2\sqrt{5}}{4} \right )=4\left (\sqrt{x^{22}+1}+(x^{5}+\varphi)^{2} \right )$$

where $\varphi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ is the golden ratio. Now the integrand assumes the following form:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^4\left(2x^{22}+\left(11\sqrt{5}+11\right)x^{17}-20\right)}{2\left(x^{22}+1\right)\sqrt{4\left(\sqrt{x^{22}+1}+(x^{5}+\varphi)^{2}\right )}}dx=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^4\left(2x^{22}+\left(11\sqrt{5}+11\right)x^{17}-20\right)}{4\left(x^{22}+1\right)^{\frac{5}{4}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x^{5}+\varphi}{\sqrt[4]{x^{22}+1}} \right)^{2}}}dx$$

Next, subs. $u=\frac{x^{5}+\varphi}{\sqrt[4]{x^{22}+1}}$, therefore

$$du=x^{4}\left[5(x^{22}+1)^{-\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{11}{2}x^{17}(x^{5}+\varphi)(x^{22}+1)^{-\frac{5}{4}} \right]dx$$

After some algebra, the integral will take the following - very simple - form:

$$\int_{0}^{\varphi}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^{2}}}=\boxed{\textrm{arcsinh}(\varphi)}$$